# Speed up MATLAB code

Tags: matlab

In my code, I have a line where I calculate the cumulative sum of a vector, A, using the cumsum() function in MATLAB (R2017b). However, between each iteration, only one element in the vector A changes, and so really it's only the values from that point onwards that change. I was wondering if there was a faster way of doing this? I have tried A(elementNumber:end) = A(elementNumber:end) - oldValue + newValue, but this isn't any faster.

Additionally, I then use the find() function at each iteration to find the first index in this cumulative sum matrix where the value first exceeds a certain value.

I was wondering if there was a faster way to perform either of these in MATLAB?

An example of the kind of code I am using is given below:

```
beta = 0.05;
S = randi(130, 15000, 1); I = randi(130, 15000, 1);
tmax = 10000; n=1; t(1) = 0; t1=0;
rates = (beta.*S.*I); cums = cumsum(rates); numI = sum(I);
Rtot = cums(end);
n=1; t(1) = 0; t1=0;
while t1<tmax
    if n>1
        newRate = beta*S(eventHouseNum)*I(eventHouseNum);
%         rates(eventHouseNum) = beta*S(eventHouseNum)*I(eventHouseNum);
        cums(eventHouseNum:end) = cums(eventHouseNum:end) - rates(eventHouseNum) + newRate;
        rates(eventHouseNum) = newRate
    end       
    Rtot = cums(end);
    if Rtot==0
        return
    end
    randNums = rand(2,1);
    dt=-log(randNums(1))/Rtot;
    P=randNums(2)*Rtot; 
    eventHouseNum = find(cums>=P,1);
    S(eventHouseNum) = S(eventHouseNum)-1;
    I(eventHouseNum) = S(eventHouseNum)+1;
    numI = numI+1; n=n+1;
    t(n)=t(n-1)+dt; t1=t(n);
    Iarray1(n) = numI;
end
```

Comment: @Wolfie I've added a shortened example of the code. Is that okay, or is there still too much there?

Comment: Profile your code, then check what makes it slow.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I know it's definitely the cumsums and the finds that are taking up the majority of the time (along with generating the random numbers - but there's nothing I can do about that).

Comment: @user112495 you can then probably produce a considerably smaller  code for us to test

Comment: @AnderBiguri I've produced something a bit simpler. In the above example, about 50% of the time is spent on cumsum(), and about 40% on find().

Comment: @Wolfie Is the above sufficient?

Comment: I am not sure if you can accelerate this any more. The reason they take all the time is because the rest of the things are such fundamental operations that take no time at all, not because they are inherently slow.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I guess I was just thinking with the cumsum is that only one element in rates actually changes each iteration, and so there's some portion of the cumulative sum that won't change at all. But I don't know if there's a way to write that that will make it faster.

Comment: Sounds like an easy for loop, why dont you try it?

Comment: @AnderBiguri In the context of the above, I tried

     cums(eventHouseNum:end) = cums(eventHouseNum:end) - previousRate + newRate

but that wasn't any faster. I'm not sure if there's a faster way to do something like this in MATLAB

Comment: No, there is no way you can replace a MATLAB builtin for faster code. They sell their product expensive becuase its already as fast as it gets

Comment: That example is much better, thanks! Looks like the thing which makes this slow is your random and potentially very small timestep... optimise the *functionality* rather than the *individual lines* when you're at the stage where low level built-ins are your bottle neck. Like reconsider if your structure is the best, often when a `while` loop is involved the answer is "It's not".